# JOIN в MySQL, специфика применения

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с вопросом, на который не совсем понимаю ответ.
В общем, когда какой JOIN следует применять. Говорю сразу, теорию читал но запутался.

Конкретно интересует формирование запроса, когда применять where, а когда on. Ведь в принципе все почти одно и тоже, а ответы на запросы получаются разные.
Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: обычный join ничем не отличается от оператора запятая в from. Но если уж пишите join то пишите ON, а если запятую - тогда условие пишется в where. это разумеется не касается left/right join которые можно записать только в такой форме

Comment: @Mike, спасибо Вам

Comment: Создавайте новый вопрос, а не меняйте старый, если новый вопрос никак не связан с предыдущим.

Comment: Откатил изменения и отменил конкурс. Если хотите задать вопрос по ассемблеру - оформите в виде отдельного вопроса.

Answer (score 7):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке достаточно все просто показано, что такое join и как с ними работать

Answer (score 4):

Кажется, автора запутала возможность делать так называемые «Old style JOIN». Зачастую, достаточно прояснить этот вопрос, чтобы всё стало понятнее.

Для SQL существует несколько стандартов, согласно которым реализуют его интерпретацию в базах данных. Есть устаревший стандарт SQL-89, а есть <s>новый</s> чуть менее устаревший [SQL-92](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92).

Когда мы делаем выборку так:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

– то используем так называемый «Old style JOIN» («Джоин старого типа») по стандарту SQL-89.

По стандарту SQL-92 этот же запрос следует делать так:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Чем лучше второй вид? **Джоины по стандарту SQL-92 позволяют более очевидно отделить условия объединения таблиц от всего остального.** Предположим, что помимо объединения нам нужно выбирать только те столбцы, в которых t1.type = 1. В этом случае условие WHERE в устаревшем типе запросов превращается в «кашу»:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.type = 1
```

А вот по стандарту SQL-92 всё остаётся чётко-разделенным «по своим местам»:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.type = 1
```

– здесь после ключевого слова **ON** по-прежнему идут условия объединения таблиц, а после ключевого слова **WHERE** идут условия фильтрации выборки.

Конечно, устаревший вид джоинов проще читается, чем конструкция `JOIN..ON`, но, как только запрос начинает разрастаться и усложняться, ситуация сразу меняется в пользу чёткого разграничения ключевых слов `WHERE` и `ON`.